# Unity2D - Blinking player Object after being hit

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this Immunity system that activates everytime the player gets hit (So all the hearts doesn't go away in just one hit), And i'm trying to make the player Object blinks or flash like in Sonic games.

Here's the Immunity part of the code:

```
private void checkImmunity()
{
    if (immunity > 0)
    {
        immunity -= Time.deltaTime;
        isImmune = true;

    }
    else
    {
        isImmune = false;
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: Please define `blink or flash` and tell us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit spriteRenderer color  using .color property: for example:

oldcolor = this.gameObject.GetComponent().color;

this.gameObject.GetComponent().color = new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.1f);

and after immunity is over:
this.gameObject.GetComponent().color = oldcolor;

for some reason its not pasting "SpriteRenderer" that is supposed to be in getcomponent part